Intermediate values of quantum circuit
I want to print the intermediate values of the quantum circuit while training in the following code which is part of the hybrid quantum-classical network. The main issue is when measuring values then the quantum circuit values are not retrievable anymore!

import pennylane as qml


n_qubits = 8
dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=n_qubits)

@qml.qnode(dev, interface="torch")
def quantum_circuit(inputs, trainable_params, random_vector):
    intermediate_values = {}

    for i in range(n_qubits):
        qml.RZ(inputs[i], wires=i)
    intermediate_values["After RZ"] = qml.state()

    qml.broadcast(unitary=qml.CNOT, pattern="ring", wires=range(n_qubits))

    for i in range(n_qubits):
        if random_vector[i] == 0:
            qml.RX(inputs[i], wires=i)
        else:
            qml.RY(inputs[i], wires=i)
    intermediate_values["After RX/RY"] = qml.state()

    expvals = [qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(i)) for i in range(n_qubits)]
    return expvals, intermediate_values



random_vector = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=n_qubits)  # Random vector of 0s and 1s

# Execute the quantum circuit
#output = quantum_circuit(inputs, trainable_params, random_vector)

# Print the random vector and output
print("Random Vector:", random_vector)

# Initialize data
#inputs = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, size=n_qubits)
#trainable_params = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, size=n_qubits)
random_vector = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=n_qubits)

# Use qml.draw to visualize the circuit
#drawer = qml.draw(quantum_circuit)
#print(drawer(inputs, trainable_params, random_vector))


If you measure in a mid of a circuit, you collapse state of measured qubit and it remains in that state. If you measure collapsed qubit again, you will get always same result (as its state is classical). May this be the problem?

I think what you are asking for is qml.Snapshot which allows you to inspect the quantum state between gates.
Instead of:
intermediate_values["After RZ"] = qml.state()

you will need to do something like:
qml.Snapshot("After_RZ")

and to get the stored states:
qml.snapshots(quantum_circuit)()

